# Ember.js: Inserting child resource's view into the main application's outlet

Tags: ember.js

By default Ember inserts the view of a child resource into an `{{outlet}}` defined by a view of a parent resource. How do I override that ? i.e. insert the child view in the `{{outlet}}` defined by the application view. Why is this the default?

**Usecase:** There is a `users` resource, with a `new` route inside it. I want the `new` to show in the applications `{{outlet}}` rather than the parent resource's `{{outlet}}`.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('users', function(){
     this.route('new');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For each route we have a `renderTemplate` method that we can overload. This gives us *full* control over the rendering of the views.

For example, we can specify into which `{{outlet}}` the view will render with `into`:

*(I assume this is your use case, but I'm a little absent-minded today.)*

```
var UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('users', {
            // Render the UsersView into the outlet found in application.hbs
            into: 'application'
        });
    }
});
```

We can also specify the name out of outlet to render into using the `outlet` property:

```
var UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('users', {
            // Render the UsersView into the outlet named "sidebar"
            outlet: 'sidebar'
        });
    }
});
```

And of course we can use a combination of both to specify both the outlet's name, as well as where that outlet is found using the `into` property.

Comment: Is it possible to append a new View instead of replacing? I have a panel I'm working on that we want to slightly overlap other elements on the page. That means we're putting it directly inside the body tag (right inside the application template in fact). Would be ideal if I could inject it programmatically rather than having to render it at initialize.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm entirely understanding, but perhaps an `Ember.ContainerView` will suit your needs? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html

Comment: Yep. Good answer. ContainerView is what I went with and it's working great. Thank you.

Comment: I encountered a strange problem with this, when rendering a child template into 'application' the parent disappears when navigating to it. Testable here: http://jsfiddle.net/genkilabs/spAbn/3/

Comment: @genkilabs: this seems to still be broken, so i created an issue for it -- https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5542